# Import Error in PythonAnywhere

Tags: python, flask, pythonanywhere, rauth

I am using the rauth library in my Flask app. The error log shows the error

```
ImportError: No module named rauth.
```

How to deal with this problem.

Comment: did you install the rauth ? 
install rauth using pip install rauth

Comment: It says `error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rauth': Permission denied`

Comment: Either use `sudo pip install rauth`, or consider creating a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) instead.

Comment: Using sudo gives the output   `sudo:unkown user: root`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation of PythonAnywhere on how to install custom packages](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/wiki/InstallingNewModules), you have to instruct pip to install into your home directory:

```
pip install --user rauth
```

Comment: PythonAnywhere dev here.  You don't actually need your username on that command line -- just the `--user` flag, ie `pip install --user rauth`.  It's a slightly confusingly named option for `pip` that tells it to install stuff in your home directory rather than trying to write to the global system libraries.

Comment: @GilesThomas thanks for the clarification, that's what you get for just skimming the docs. I updated my answer from original `pip install --user <your_username> rauth` for anyone looking this up in the future

Answer (score 1):

To install rauth please do

python -m pip install rauth

If its giving permission denied error while installing then It seems the user as which you are logged in to the system has no permission to access the file. Please login to system as a user who has all permission to acess files i mean to say login as the system's main admin and then try.